# Changing/syncing the "About Me" profile description in SE sites and on the global SE profile

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-sync

I have accounts in several SE network sites. The first one was on **StackOverflow**. I bothered to update the "About Me" box in **SO** and **Photo.SE**. In some of the other sites, and specifically in the global **SE** profile, the "About Me" description is synced with the **SO** one.

1. How can I unsync (leave empty) the global box, or box in any other site?
2. Can I select which of the populated site boxes to sync with, in a site where I do not explicitly edit the box?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I unsync (leave empty) the global box, or box in any other site?

You cannot specifically leave the global box empty. You would need to empty the profile on the site the global box is copying from (your oldest profile).

> Can I select which of the populated site boxes to sync with, in a site where I do not explicitly edit the box?

You need to either manually edit the each site's profile one-at-a-time, or use the "Save and Copy Profile to All Sites" button to modify all profiles at once. No more nuanced option is available, and you cannot control this behaviour per-field.

Comment: Two "no"s then... Well, here's an opportunity for feature enhancement. Now, where do I request that?

Comment: You could create a new post here and tag it feature-request. First you should do a search to see if existing feature requests already exist. My ten seconds of looking didn't turn up anything, but I'd be a little surprised if it had never been asked. I would also really appreciate having an easier way to manage many profiles.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that research before posting *this* post. Hopefully I did not miss anything. Anyway, if I did miss it, it means that the request was previously ignored/rejected/postponed, so raising this issue again would be a good idea...