# Better management of User Profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, profile-copying, profile-sync

Earlier, I was looking for [a way of managing my "About Me" boxes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230005/155173) across the different SE sites. Seems like the features are not available at this time. I'd like to suggest a new way of managing user's profiles across the sites.

Many of the sites share the same themes. For example, [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), etc. are all programming/computers related. [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), etc. are science related.

It makes sense to arrange the user's profiles, and specifically the "About Me" box, in groups as well. Thus, all programming sites share one profile with programming related description and all science sites will share a different profile.

I think that an improved feature for profile management would be an option to sync a profile field in a site with the same field on any other site. For a coarser granularity, syncing the whole profile is almost as good, and requires storing far less interconnect information.

Further improving it would be to make the fields/profiles linked together rather than just sync on demand. This way, changing a field in any one of the grouped sites will have immediate effect on all linked-to profiles on the other sites in the group.

Comment: Do you update this *About me* section so often that you can't copy-paste text from one site to another? It would be interesting to know the average number of sites accounts for each user. Do many users use so many Stack Exchange sites that updating the *About me* section takes a long time?

Comment: @n.1 - No, I do not update it so often (barely, actually. However, I do have more accounts than what I'd consider a low effort to manually update each.

Comment: @random - I wonder why I did not see that post when searching. The two requests share a lot of ideas indeed. I am not sure it is an exact dup, though. Anyway, he did not get a meaningful response, and the feature is still not available 2 years later (!), so re-requesting may be a good idea.