# How can I edit my network profile independently?

Tags: support, network-profile

My oldest account on the network is Area 51, followed by Mi Yodeya.  I recently filled out the "about me" section on Mi Yodeya (but nowhere else) and did *not* choose the "update all sites" option because my blurb is pretty specific to that site.  I intended to have that blurb on exactly one site.  I was surprised tonight to discover that that blurb is now on my network profile, where I see no "edit" link.

Am I stuck with either having a site-specific blurb as my network blurb (because it's my first non-Area-51 site) or rewriting it to be more general?  Or is there some way that I can independently edit the network profile?  (Or designate a different site as the default?)

[This feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132239/162102) shows that someone else had this problem too, but I'm asking for support, not for a new feature, so I'm asking this separately.

Comment: Strongly related: [Changing/syncing the "About Me" profile description in SE sites and on the global SE profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230005)

Comment: I fear the answer is "you can't, this is not possible".

Comment: However since you're a "gold member" of SE, you might get special treatment, if I were you I would email the team asking to manually change the network profile to what I want. Maybe they will do it maybe not, but worth trying IMO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure being a moderator makes me a "gold member" in anybody's eyes, but it's worth a shot.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I missed you're a mod, lol! Was talking about four 10k+ accounts in the network. :-)

Comment: Oh, does 10k mean something to the greater SE community?  I mean, on two of those sites 10k is pretty unusual (smaller, lower-rep sites) so it means something *there*, but SOians would probably just say "yeah, so?". :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the network profile just pulls the bio from your oldest account on the network. Not sure why they went with *oldest* account, versus something like *top* account. If not personalizing the network profile, at least let us select which site it pulls from. :/

Comment: And apparently Area 51 doesn't count, since that's actually my oldest account but it didn't pull from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can now [sync your network profile with any site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275694/162102), not just the oldest.  Further, updates are no longer auto-synchronized; the network profile's "about me" only gets updated when you explicitly do so by clicking on the circled link:

[image: "update profile info" link]

You can sync to a different site, or even temporarily change the text somewhere, sync, and then restore the text you had on that site.  I've got plenty of 101-rep sites with no customization lying around, so I could use one of those to write a custom profile, sync, and then delete it from that site.

It's not a direct "edit" link on the network profile, but it's close enough.

Comment: There's also a bug with this - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277870/my-se-profile-keeps-resetting-to-my-stack-overflow-profile-despite-me-selecting - when you create a new account that resets your network profile to that of the newly created account