# Use another profile other than the oldest when joining new community or site

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts

All the new communities that I join are using my oldest profile (Tex/LateX.SE) but I would rather they link to my profile at Math.SE.

Is there a simple way to accomplish that? I navigated the site but could not find a way to do so.

This is not the same as [How can I edit my network profile independently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231419/how-can-i-edit-my-network-profile-independently?noredirect=1&lq=1) as this one here does not ask about the Network Profile, but rather creating new "ordinary" accounts across Stack Exchange.

Comment: @random why didn't you reopen when editing? I made mistake when closing it years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copying of the oldest profile is by design.

The only way would be to make your Tex/Latex profile read the same as your Math [sic] profile.

I'd suggest opening a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to allow the user to choose which profile to sync with it defaulting to the oldest.

Comment: Can someone explain the reasoning behind this ‘design’?

Comment: @AntonSherwood this answer is outdated. Chris can you please update it? See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298416/152859) for up-to-date information.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - nope. It still copies your oldest profile when creating a new account. The only bit that's wrong is the syncing of the network profile.