# Modification of StackExchange network profile

Tags: support, profile-page, network-profile

A few years ago I created an account on Askubuntu. Now I would like to change my SE network profile information because I am a member of several more SE sites.

However, It seems that the only way that I could do this would be to go back and modify my profile on my original Askubuntu  account.

How would I go about changing my network profile without changing my profile on Askubuntu?

Comment: You can't. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231419/how-can-i-edit-my-network-profile-independently?lq=1 (possible duplicate)