# When creating a new account, my SE network profile is reset to the text entered for the new account

Tags: bug, status-norepro, network-profile, profile-sync

According to this answer [Don't force sync with my oldest account on my network profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254566/dont-force-sync-with-my-oldest-account-on-my-network-profile/275694#275694) states:

> Note that this is a one time copy, not an ongoing sync. If you want to update your profile on stackexchange.com after making changes on your Q&A site of choice, you'll need to repeat this process.

However, my profile text (but **not** my profile image) keeps getting reset.

I have now twice synced my SE profile to my MSE profile and both times as some indeterminate time later it had reset itself back to my SO profile text. I assume it's picking SO as that's my oldest account. I would really like it to stick with my MSE profile.

I have just (2016-12-01 12:30 UTC) had it reset again. This time it was close enough to another event to make me think that they are linked. I'd just created a new account (on Startups to flag some spam) and as it had copied my SO profile I edited the new profile to remove the SO specific stuff. When I refreshed my network profile page (https://stackexchange.com/users/23619/chrisf?tab=accounts) the profile information, but not the profile picture, had been reset. In this case it was reset to being blank which is the "text" I had entered into the profile on Startups.

Comment: No repro for me, I created a new account, edited only on the new site, network profile kept my MSE info.

Comment: @ShadowWizard odd. Happens all the time for me.

Comment: hmm.... well, hopefully a dev would have better luck reproducing. :)

Comment: Does this still happen?  It hasn't happened to me with my last several new accounts.

Comment: @Monica I haven't created a new account in a while but it always seems to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

I have just created a new account and my network profile has remained constant.