# Network profile (about me) automatically syncs to the oldest account after some time

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, network-profile, profile-sync

After recognizing [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) of *[Don't force sync with my oldest account on my network profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254566/dont-force-sync-with-my-oldest-account-on-my-network-profile)*, I changed (my oldest account is on *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)*) my network-profile to that of *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)* by the `Update profile info` feature.

After some weeks when I checked my [network-profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4140743/pandya), it was showing about-me corresponding to *Ask Ubuntu* again. I ignored and re-set it to that of *Unix & Linux* again. **But** after some weeks (today), I've checked my [network-profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4140743/pandya), it was showing about-me corresponding to *Ask Ubuntu* again, and I've to re-set it again. *I didn't ignore and posted this question!*

Note: I may have updated about-me on some communities and joined some communities, but *neither* touched the network-profile (except re-setting) *nor* used `Save and copy all changes to all Stack Exchange communities`.

Anyway, I think it should be a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

By the way, does joining new communities and/or updating about-me of particular communities (consider not using either `Save and copy all changes to all Stack Exchange communities` nor changing profile that has set for network profile) affect the network profile?

Comment: I reported this some time ago - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277870/my-se-profile-keeps-resetting-to-my-stack-overflow-profile-despite-me-selecting - but it stopped happening so I decided that it was "no repro".

Comment: @ChrisF Bug is verified by me more than three times.